# Generate list of Azure AD email addresses from FirstName and LastName

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-active-directory

I have a CSV file with two columns, firstname and lastname, which I'm trying to obtain the email addresses for.  How would I go about creating a Powershell script which will run through the list and extract the email address of the person from Azure AD?  I thought the following code would work but it seems I'm getting an error.

```
Import-Csv -Path "C:\path\to\file.csv" | ForEach-Object {
    $firstName = $_.FirstName
    $lastName = $_.LastName
    $user = Get-AzureADUser -Filter "startswith(givenName,'$firstName') and surname eq '$lastName'"
    if ($user) {
        Write-Output "$($user.UserPrincipalName)"
    }
}
```

Error:

```
Get-AzureADUser : Error occurred while executing GetUsers 
Code: Request_UnsupportedQuery
Message: Unsupported or invalid query filter clause specified for property 'givenName' 
of resource 'User'.
RequestId: 6da6daf9-2a2f-4f91-80e0-de152a2d7a62
DateTimeStamp: Thu, 07 Dec 2023 23:09:52 GMT
HttpStatusCode: BadRequest
HttpStatusDescription: Bad Request
HttpResponseStatus: Completed
At line:5 char:13
+     $user = Get-AzureADUser -Filter "startswith(givenName,'$firstName ...
+             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-AzureADUser], ApiException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Open.AzureAD16.Client.ApiException,Microsoft.Op 
   en.AzureAD16.PowerShell.GetUser
```

Comment: The way this site works is that you ask a question about **your code**.  It's not a site where people write the code for you.  Please edit your question and add in the code segment that demonstrates your best attempt, and then tell us the results you're getting versus the results you expect to get.  If you have no clue how to approach this topic, that's an indicator that you need to put more effort into researching it, or more effort into telling us what you have researched and found and what didn't work and why.

Comment: [How much effort is expected](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: I don't have access to an Azure AD to test but since the error states that the filter clause for `givenName` is invalid or unsupported I'd start with chaning this part of the query to something simpler. ‍♂️ Why did you actually use `startswith()`? Don't you have the complete first names of your users in your CSV file?

Answer (score 1):

My **CSV file** looks like below:

[image]

**To fetch the User Principal Names** of the users, make use of below PowerShell script:

```
Connect-AzureAD

Import-Csv -Path "C:\Users\rukmini\Downloads\AzureADUPN.csv" | ForEach-Object {
    $firstName = $_.FirstName
    $lastName = $_.LastName

    # Remove leading and trailing spaces from names
    $firstName = $firstName.Trim()
    $lastName = $lastName.Trim()

   $filter = "givenName eq '$firstName' and surname eq '$lastName'"

    try {
        $user = Get-AzureADUser -Filter $filter -ErrorAction Stop
        Write-Output "$($user.UserPrincipalName)"
    } catch {
        Write-Output "User not found for $firstName $lastName"
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
ruk@xxx.onmicrosoft.com
ruktest@xxx.onmicrosoft.com
sampleusertest@xxx.onmicrosoft.com
```

[image]

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) ... the second one is nearly unreadable.

Comment: I uploaded script and output in text format too

Comment: So the image is actually not needed anymore!?   ... and if someone wants to use your CSV data they have to type it by themselfs. ☝